# Fetch current AWS security groups limit using python/node.js

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

everybody!

Hope you all doing good.

I have a lambda function alerts teams upon reaching AWS service limits, one of the scenarios out of it is I need to fetch the current security groups limit(of course by default, it is 500, but it may change as we go with limit extension.)from AWS and compare that with current usage and if it is anywhere close to the limit it should alert. I'm able to get the alerts now. But, every time I extend the security groups limit I need to update lambda function just because I'd hardcoded earlier and I want to avoid by fetching the limit automatically.

Can somebody help me how do I solve this?

thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at this SO question : https://serverfault.com/questions/731021/how-to-programatically-find-all-my-aws-accounts-limits

Comment: At this time, Aws is not support that API so you cannot get that info dynamic. But I have an idea. You use boto3 to create new Security Group every X minutes with [dry-run option](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_security_group). If it return error limit so you will know your account reach limitation. I did not try yet but you can try it. If ok, lets me know. Thanks.